# Touch Board from Bare Conductive not uploading arduino code example

Tags: arduino-ide, bare-conductive

I have an issue with this example https://github.com/BareConductive/mpr121/tree/public/MPR121/Examples/SimpleTouch when trying to upload it. Also, there was an issue when compiling it, however, the arduino suggested the change (wrong naming) that made the code compile. However, no upload. I have tried both boards available and both ports available *that are showing as options.

I get this verbose output:

```
processing.app.debug.RunnerException
    at cc.arduino.packages.uploaders.SerialUploader.uploadUsingPreferences(SerialUploader.java:152)
    at cc.arduino.UploaderUtils.upload(UploaderUtils.java:77)
    at processing.app.SketchController.upload(SketchController.java:732)
    at processing.app.SketchController.exportApplet(SketchController.java:703)
    at processing.app.Editor$UploadHandler.run(Editor.java:2061)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: processing.app.SerialException: Error touching serial port '/dev/cu.BLTH'.
    at processing.app.Serial.touchForCDCReset(Serial.java:107)
    at cc.arduino.packages.uploaders.SerialUploader.uploadUsingPreferences(SerialUploader.java:136)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: jssc.SerialPortException: Port name - /dev/cu.BLTH; Method name - openPort(); Exception type - Port busy.
    at jssc.SerialPort.openPort(SerialPort.java:164)
    at processing.app.Serial.touchForCDCReset(Serial.java:101)
    ... 6 more
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: try compiling and uploading an empty sketch ... one that has only `void setup() {}` and `void loop() {}` ... the github library is probably irrelevant to your question

Comment: This seems to be a problem with the Arduino IDE, not with your sketch. What OS are you using and what version of the Arduino IDE? How did you install it?

Comment: `/dev/cu.BLTH` This thing is (or was) supposedly an Arduino Leonardo so far the IDE is concerned and would that not present itself as `cu.BLTH`. If there's more to this than just choosing the wrong port, maybe make that clear.

Comment: @jsotola and others, thank you, I have just tried uploading an empty sketch over both available ports and I get the same results except that with the second port I also get the> avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
 // Arduino works fine with arduino uno.

Comment: @chrisl I am on Mac OS Monterey 12.4 and Arduino IDE 1.8.19

Comment: Verify that something relevant shows up in System Information if and only if the board is attached. If not, make sure your micro-usb cable is not the charging-only variety.